# application layers

Tags: java, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

Theoretically, in general:

- Data access layer holds database connections and queries.
- Business layer holds the model and the logics.
- Service layer holds the main services the application services.
- Presentation layer holds the website.

  1. Am I right? did I miss something?
  2. What is the infrastructure layer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd say you've described the layers correctly.

In my mind infrastructure can represent two things:

1. Cross cutting concerns - things like logging/auditing, authentication/security etc. I prefer to use [Aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to deal with these types of things.
2. Third party systems/components/libraries that your application makes use of, such as a credit card payment gateway for example. Even the database platform you have chosen could be considered infrastructure.

Comment: So if I would have a project like structuremap (IoC container) for example, does it considered as infrastructure?

Comment: @Naor: Yeah, I'd say so. Its an infrastructure/implementation component that is nothing to do with the application logic.

Answer (score 0):

The infrastructure layer tends to turn up in DDD and MVVM type projects.  There's a simple diagram and quick explanation of the layers in DDD here.

http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/architecture.html

It's based on a Java implementation, but the descriptions still hold up apart from the odd bit of Java terminology.